# Way to display Rails error page instead of vague Heroku error pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Developing a rails app on localhost, whenever there is an error you can see the error in detail on the rails page that comes up. But, on Heroku, the only thing that appears when there is an error, is "We're sorry, but something went wrong." with no information. I've seen the logs, and that doesn't seem to help. Is there a way to replace that generic Heroku error page, with the detailed Rails error page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a heroku-specific issue, but a *production environment* one.  In any production setting, you can display full errors on by changing this line in your `config/environments/production.rb`

```
config.consider_all_requests_local = false
```

to

```
config.consider_all_requests_local  = true
```

Note that a better alternative so it's not visible to users is to continue to display the production style error, and tail the log files instead using:

```
heroku logs --app <yourappname> --tail
```

This will run a stream of the log file so you don't miss anything rather than just the last 40 lines.

If you aren't seeing enough information, then in `config/environments/production` add or change the log_level to debug

```
config.log_level = :info
```

Or you could reset the log level using an environment variable, so you can just remove it and restart rather than redeploying with:

```
heroku config:add LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG --app <yourappname>
```

Answer (score 2):

This could get you going..

*routes.rb*

```
match "/404", :to => "exceptions#some_error"
match "/500", :to => "exceptions#some_error"
#add some more?
```

so then,

```
class ExceptionsController < ApplicationController

  def some_error
      @exception = env["action_dispatch.exception"]
      @status_code = ActionDispatch::ExceptionWrapper.new(env, @exception).status_code
  end

end
```

a view page finally, to display sort of exception, you will be fixing.

Answer (score 1):

In your rails app, under `config/environments/production.rb`, try changing

`config.consider_all_requests_local = false`

to

`config.consider_all_requests_local = true`

Note: You may want to set up a new environment and deploy that to Heroku when you want to see the normal rails error messages.  Maybe something like `staging` or `testing` since you don't want users seeing these kinds of errors on a live site.

Answer (score 0):

I feel your pain. Try running `heroku run rails console` for a clearer error. Hope that helps